# Are Laplace Transforms a Special Case of Fourier Transforms?

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-transforms

A Laplace Transform is based on the integral:

$F(\xi) = \int_0^{\infty} f(x) e^ {-\xi x}\,dx.$

In a roundabout way, a Fourier transform can get to $\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\ e^{- 2\pi i x \xi}\,dx,$
Also, they both seem to use convolutions and transposes in "indirect" forms of "multiplication."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your formula for the Laplace transform is wrong.  It should be
$F(\xi) = \int_0^\infty f(x) e^{-\xi x}\, dx$.  But yes, when $\xi$ is imaginary you have (up to normalization) the Fourier transform of $f$ (considered as a function on $(-\infty, \infty)$ which is 0 on $(-\infty, 0)$).

Comment: Fixed the Laplace transform per your text.

Comment: @Robert: Could you elaborate? I've often wondered why these two transforms seem to be treated as quite separate things when there's an obvious connection between them.

Comment: As Robert said. But the properties of the two transforms are so different that (to me) the answer to the question in your title is a resounding: No.

Comment: For example, the Bromwich integral for inverting the Laplace transform is really an inverse Fourier transform.  See chapter 9 of Dettman, "Applied Complex Variables" 
http://books.google.ca/books?id=vmZ6PVtaexwC

Comment: See also the Paley-Wiener theorems (e.g. Rudin, "Real and Complex Analysis", sec. 19.1 and 19.2).  Remarkably, Rudin does not mention the name Laplace.

Comment: Also Reed & Simon, "Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics II: Fourier Analysis, Self-Adjointness", sec. IX.3.  They don't mention Laplace either, except in the Notes where they refer to Schwartz's paper "Transformation de Laplace des distributions".

Comment: Should you not say Fourier Transforms are a special case of Laplace Transforms? (Laplace is more general.)

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7UvtU75NXTg). that is indeed the case that a Laplace transform is a generalized version of the Fourier transform.

Fourier series work well for functions that approach zero as t goes to $(-\infty, and, \infty)$. It does not work for functions that go to a large number as t goes to either $(-\infty, or, \infty)$. La place's solution for managing the second type of function is to multiply it by a negative exponential as a dampener, to transform the function to F(t). This transformation creates an F(t) that is amenable to Fourier methods.

Thus, a Laplace transform of f(t) is equivalent to the Fourier transform of F(t).